# Assembly function doesnt stop

Tags: assembly, infinite

I'm trying to display 3 messages,one of them using a function.But that function never stops displaying the message.
This is the code:

```
.model small
.data
message db "Hello from function!$"  
message1 db "Hello from the court!$" 
message2 db "Hello from the second court!$" 
.code
function proc
  mov dx,offset message;
  mov ah,9; 
int 21h;
endp


mov ax,@data;
mov ds,ax;

call function

lea dx,message1;
mov ah,9;
int 21;

call function

lea dx,message2;
mov ah,9;
int 21;

call function

mov ax,4c00h;
int 21h;
```

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger. It's just a few lines so it shouldn't take long.

Comment: After the function outputs the "Hello from function" message,the ret instruction is processed and the execution doesnt continue from mov ax,@data but looks into memory locations that are empty(NULL).I'm using emu8086 to emulate and execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed `RET` at the end of `function`:

```
function proc
  mov dx,offset message
  mov ah,9
  int 21h
  RET
endp
```

If you don't put the `RET` here you'll find that the recursion occures as `function` called multiple times (while the stack don't exceeded).

Comment: Your code starts from the `function`. So the `RET` returns to the OS. Move `function` to the end of the code section.